# SQL Query matching multiple values in multiple columns - best/fastest way?

Tags: sql, join, multiple-columns, union, matching

Ultimately I need to calculate the sum of a column from all the entries retrieved by a query.  My question is what will be the fastest/most efficient way to do this.

The background is as follows:

I am initially provided with multiple items as a comma separated string eg: A1, A2, B1, B3, C2, C3

Each of these items in turn can have multiple (sometimes hundreds) related sub-items represented in a table ("Item_Table")

ITEM_TABLE example:

| ITEM | SUB_ITEM |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | A1001 |
| A1 | A1002 |
| A2 | A2001 |
| A2 | A2002 |
| A3 | A3001 |
| A3 | A3002 |
| B1 | B1001 |
| B1 | B1002 |
| B2 | B2001 |
| B2 | B2002 |
| B3 | B3001 |
| B3 | B3002 |
| C1 | C1001 |
| C1 | C1002 |
| C2 | C2001 |
| C2 | C2002 |
| C3 | C3001 |
| C3 | C3002 |

The second table ("Item_Freq_Table") that I need to query has combinations of these sub-items (2 columns for each item) and a frequency column which is what I ultimately need to sum.

ITEM_FREQ_TABLE example:

| TABLEKEY | A_Item_1 | A_Item_2 | B_Item_1 | B_Item_2 | C_Item_1 | C_Item_2 | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1001 | A1001 | B1001 | B1001 | C2001 | C3002 | 0.0123 |
| 2 | A1001 | A2001 | B1001 | B2001 | C1002 | C1001 | 0.0456 |
| 3 | A1001 | A2002 | B1002 | B2001 | C3001 | C3001 | 0.0789 |
| 4 | A2001 | A2002 | B2001 | B2001 | C1001 | C3001 | 0.0321 |
| 5 | A2002 | A2002 | B2002 | B3001 | C3002 | C3002 | 0.0654 |
| 6 | A1001 | A3001 | B1001 | B3002 | C1002 | C2002 | 0.0987 |
| 7 | A3001 | A3002 | B2001 | B2002 | C1001 | C1002 | 0.0135 |
| 8 | A3001 | A3001 | B3002 | B3002 | C1001 | C3001 | 0.0246 |

I need to sum the frequency for each entry (row) that matches at least one of the sub-items (as represented in initial item string) and not duplicate-count any of the entries.

In this above example, all entries except that with TableKey 7 should be retrieved and frequency total to 0.3576

I tried the following, which works, but I'm not sure it is the best/fastest option...

```
DECLARE @Initial_String varchar(6000)

    SET @Initial_String = 'A1, A2, B1, B3, C2, C3'

    DECLARE @String_NEW varchar(6000)

    SET @String_NEW =  replace(@Initial_String,' ','')

    DECLARE @Split_Item_Table as table
       (
       Split_Item varchar(20)
       )

    INSERT INTO @Split_Item_Table SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@String_NEW, ',')

    SELECT
        sum(a.Frequency) as Sum_Freq
    FROM
    (
     SELECT 
       n.[TableKey]
      ,n.[A_Item_1]
      ,n.[A_Item_2]
      ,n.[B_Item_1]
      ,n.[B_Item_2]
      ,n.[C_Item_1]
      ,n.[C_Item_2]
      ,n.[Frequency]
     FROM [dbo].[ITEM_FREQ_TABLE] n
     inner join [dbo].[ITEM_TABLE] c on n.A_Item_1 = c.SUB_ITEM
     WHERE c.ITEM in (SELECT Split_Item FROM @Split_Item_Table WHERE Split_Item like 'A%')

     UNION

     SELECT 
       n.[TableKey]
      ,n.[A_Item_1]
      ,n.[A_Item_2]
      ,n.[B_Item_1]
      ,n.[B_Item_2]
      ,n.[C_Item_1]
      ,n.[C_Item_2]
      ,n.[Frequency]
     FROM [dbo].[ITEM_FREQ_TABLE] n
     inner join [dbo].[ITEM_TABLE] c on n.A_Item_2 = c.SUB_ITEM
     WHERE c.ITEM in (SELECT Split_Item FROM @Split_Item_Table WHERE Split_Item like 'A%')

     UNION

     SELECT 
       n.[TableKey]
      ,n.[A_Item_1]
      ,n.[A_Item_2]
      ,n.[B_Item_1]
      ,n.[B_Item_2]
      ,n.[C_Item_1]
      ,n.[C_Item_2]
      ,n.[Frequency]
     FROM [dbo].[ITEM_FREQ_TABLE] n
     inner join [dbo].[ITEM_TABLE] c on n.B_Item_1 = c.SUB_ITEM
     WHERE c.ITEM in (SELECT Split_Item FROM @Split_Item_Table WHERE Split_Item like 'B%')

     UNION

     SELECT 
       n.[TableKey]
      ,n.[A_Item_1]
      ,n.[A_Item_2]
      ,n.[B_Item_1]
      ,n.[B_Item_2]
      ,n.[C_Item_1]
      ,n.[C_Item_2]
      ,n.[Frequency]
     FROM [dbo].[ITEM_FREQ_TABLE] n
     inner join [dbo].[ITEM_TABLE] c on n.B_Item_2 = c.SUB_ITEM
     WHERE c.ITEM in (SELECT Split_Item FROM @Split_Item_Table WHERE Split_Item like 'B%')

     UNION

     SELECT 
       n.[TableKey]
      ,n.[A_Item_1]
      ,n.[A_Item_2]
      ,n.[B_Item_1]
      ,n.[B_Item_2]
      ,n.[C_Item_1]
      ,n.[C_Item_2]
      ,n.[Frequency]
     FROM [dbo].[ITEM_FREQ_TABLE] n
     inner join [dbo].[ITEM_TABLE] c on n.C_Item_1 = c.SUB_ITEM
     WHERE c.ITEM in (SELECT Split_Item FROM @Split_Item_Table WHERE Split_Item like 'C%')

     UNION

     SELECT 
       n.[TableKey]
      ,n.[A_Item_1]
      ,n.[A_Item_2]
      ,n.[B_Item_1]
      ,n.[B_Item_2]
      ,n.[C_Item_1]
      ,n.[C_Item_2]
      ,n.[Frequency]
     FROM [dbo].[ITEM_FREQ_TABLE] n
     inner join [dbo].[ITEM_TABLE] c on n.C_Item_2 = c.SUB_ITEM
     WHERE c.ITEM in (SELECT Split_Item FROM @Split_Item_Table WHERE Split_Item like 'C%')
    )a
```

Comment: If your code works then probably you should be asking on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you are have performance issues we would need to know the full table schema, indexes and the actual execution plan at a minimum, not least also details of which RDBMS and version.